# How to add permissions to a project in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm trying to set up a GCP billing alert using Terraform. The [docs say](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/billing_budget):

> Your account must have the serviceusage.services.use permission on the billing_project you defined.

The [Google docs](https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/access-control) also say to set this permission on the project but don't say how.

How can I add that permission to my project (either via the console or ideally Terraform) to allow myself to create billing alerts?

My provider currently looks like this:

```
provider "google-beta" {
  alias                 = "billing"
  billing_project       = "me-${var.env}"
  project               = "me-${var.env}"
  region                = "europe-west1"
  zone                  = "europe-west1-d"
  user_project_override = true
}
```

Comment: You don't grant permissions/roles to a project, but on an account (user or service). What did you try to do?

Comment: 1) CLI: **gcloud services enable serviceusage.googleapis.com** 2) GUI: https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/serviceusage.googleapis.com

Answer (score 0):

Cloud budgets can only be created and managed by users with a Billing Account Administrator role, or a custom role with appropriate budget management permissions. This means that project owners without the Billing Account Admin role cannot create budgets for their respective projects.

To create a budget for your Cloud Billing account, you need a role that includes the following [permissions](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#billing-roles) on the Cloud Billing account:

- [billing.budgets.create](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/custom-roles#budget_alerts) to create a new budget.
- [billing.budgets.get and billing.budgets.list](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/custom-roles#budget_alerts) to view all budgets for the Cloud Billing account.

To gain these permissions, ask your administrator to grant you one of the following [Cloud Billing IAM](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/billing-access) roles on your Cloud Billing account:

- Billing Account Administrator
- Billing Account Costs Manager

Steps to add or remove Cloud Billing permissions:

1.Sign in to the Google Cloud Console.

- Open the Cloud Console **Navigation menu** and then select **Billing**.
- If you have more than one Cloud Billing account, do one of the following:

  - To manage Cloud Billing for the current project, select **Go to linked billing account.**
  - To locate a different Cloud Billing account, select **Manage billing accounts** and then choose the account that you want to manage.

2. In the Billing navigation menu, click **Account management**.
3. Use the **Permissions** panel to edit permissions for the selected Cloud Billing account. If the panel isn't already visible, click **SHOW INFO PANEL** to open it.

The **Permissions panel** is organized by role, along with the number of principals that have each role. For example, in your permissions panel, you might see
- Billing Account Administrator (2 principals)
- Billing Account User (6 principals)
- Billing Account Viewer (10 principals)

You can grant multiple roles to the same principal.

To **view the list of principals** that have a role, click the **role name** to expand (or collapse) the list of principals.

Refer to the links to [update Cloud Billing permissions](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/billing-access#update-cloud-billing-permissions) and [creating budget alerts.](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/budgets#overview)